# Omit land in autoplot.bathy marmap package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I'm trying to plot the Mediterranean using the autoplot.bathy() to allow me to plot a pretty grouped and faceted scatterplot through ggplot2. My graph looks great, but the only problem is there's so much land. Is there a way to only plot the sea, or to grey out the land? I know I can plot without land simply by using plot(med, image=TRUE), however this is no good as I want to do it through ggplot.

The land is very distracting when I plot the data points.
[image]
I've tried using scale_fill_gradient2(low="dodgerblue4", mid="lightblue", high="white") but then it ruins the sea gradients.

Here is my code (for this, no example data is needed so I have commented out the data part)

```
med<-getNOAA.bathy(lon1=-5,lon2=36.24583, lat1=30.25417,lat2= 45)

autoplot.bathy(med, geom=c("r", "c"), colour="white", mapping = NULL, alpha=0.7) + 
  scale_fill_etopo()+
#  geom_point(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, col=as.factor(class)), data=newdf, alpha=0.8)+
#  facet_grid(id ~ .)+
  xlab("Longitude") + 
  ylab("Latitude")
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Just worked out a hacky solution by setting limits and making the `na.value` the same colour as the contour lines!

```
autoplot.bathy(med, geom=c("r", "c"), colour="lightgrey", mapping = NULL) +
scale_fill_gradient2(low="darkblue", mid="lightblue", high="white", limits = c(-4000, 0), na.value = "lightgrey")
```

[image]